# How to prevent a current value to be printed in array except others

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

How can I prevent the current value to be printed in array I mean if I have an array something like this

```
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Grapes', 'Apples', 'Orange'];
```

and I am looping out using for loop like thing :

```
fLen = fruits.length;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";

    for (j = 0; j<fLen; j++) {
    text+=fruits[j];
    }
}

text += "</ul>";
```

**The Output is:**

```
Banana
Banana Grapes Apples Orange 
Grapes
Banana Grapes Apples Orange 
Apples
Banana Grapes Apples Orange 
Orange
Banana Grapes Apples Orange
```

But,

**What I want:**

I want the **output** like thing

```
Banana
Grapes Apples Orange 
Grapes
Banana Apples Orange 
Apples
Banana Grapes Orange 
Orange
Banana Grapes Apples
```

means the current value should not be present in its second output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do only one loop using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Grapes', 'Apples', 'Orange'],
    result = fruits.reduce((acc, val, ind, arr) => {
      acc += `<li>${val}</li>` + arr.join(' ').replace(val, '').trim();
      if (++ind === arr.length) {
        acc += '</ul>';
      }
      return acc;
    }, '<ul>');

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result;
```

```css
li {list-style: none;}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: If I want to run if else loop inside the acc is it right to do that

Comment: @user7791702 applied your suggestion for clarity in the code.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
fLen = fruits.length;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";

    for (j = 0; j<fLen; j++) {
        if (j != i) {
            text+=fruits[j];
        }
    }
}

text += "</ul>";
```

Just place a check to skip current index, which in your case is `i`

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an `if` condition which checks whether the index of both loops is same to the second `for` loop.

```js
        var fruits = ['Banana', 'Grapes', 'Apples', 'Orange'];
        fLen = fruits.length;
        text = "<ul>";
        for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
            text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";

            for (j = 0; j < fLen; j++) {
              if (i !== j) {
                text += fruits[j] + ' ';
              }
            }
        }

        text += "</ul>";
        
        
        document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

duplicate the array for every iteration i.e. 4 times in a loop and pop consecutively different leader elements and then print the rest.

```
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Grapes', 'Apples', 'Orange'];
for (i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
var temp=fruits;
var leader=temp.pop(fruits[i]);
//print leader
for(int j=0;j<temp.length;j++){
  //print temp[j]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Grapes', 'Apples', 'Orange'];

var fLen = fruits.length;
var text = "<ul>";



fruits.forEach(function(fruit, i, array){
    text += "<li>" + fruit + "</li>";

    for (j = 0; j<fLen; j++) {

        if(j != i){
              text += fruits[j];
        }
    }
});

text += "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

```
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Grapes', 'Apples', 'Orange'];
var text = '<ul>';
fruits.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
  text += '<li>'+ element+'</br>';
  var newArray = array.map(function (element2, index2) {
    if(index != index2) {
      text += element2 + ' ';
    }
  });
  text +='</li>';
});
text += '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

why so complicated:

```
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Grapes', 'Apples', 'Orange'];
var text=`<ul>${fruits.map(e=>`<li>${e}</li>${fruits.filter(k => k!=e ? k : '')}`)}</ul>`.replace(/,/g, " ");
console.log(text);
```